# How can the location of Cargo's configuration directory be overridden?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

It seems that the default behavior of Cargo when searching for its configuration directory is to look in the current user's home directory (`~/.cargo` on my system). How can this behavior be modified to make Cargo look in a user-supplied directory instead?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> #### Environment variables Cargo reads
>
> You can override these environment variables to change Cargo's
>   behavior on your system:
>
> - `CARGO_HOME` — Cargo maintains a local cache of the registry index and of git   checkouts of crates.  By default these are stored under
>     `$HOME/.cargo`, but   this variable overrides the location of this
>     directory. Once a crate is cached   it is not removed by the clean
>     command.
> - `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` — Location of where to place all generated artifacts,   relative to the current working directory.
> - `RUSTC` — Instead of running `rustc`, Cargo will execute this specified   compiler instead.
> - `RUSTC_WRAPPER` — Instead of simply running `rustc`, Cargo will execute this   specified wrapper instead, passing as its commandline
>     arguments the rustc   invocation, with the first argument being rustc.
> - `RUSTDOC` — Instead of running `rustdoc`, Cargo will execute this specified   `rustdoc` instance instead.
> - `RUSTDOCFLAGS` — A space-separated list of custom flags to pass to all `rustdoc`   invocations that Cargo performs. In contrast with
>     `cargo rustdoc`, this is   useful for passing a flag to *all*
>     `rustdoc` instances.
> - `RUSTFLAGS` — A space-separated list of custom flags to pass to all compiler   invocations that Cargo performs. In contrast with `cargo rustc`,
>     this is   useful for passing a flag to *all* compiler
>     instances.
> - `CARGO_INCREMENTAL` — If this is set to 1 then Cargo will force incremental   compilation to be enabled for the current compilation,
>     and when set to 0 it   will force disabling it. If this env var isn't
>     present then cargo's defaults   will otherwise be used.
> - `CARGO_CACHE_RUSTC_INFO` — If this is set to 0 then Cargo will not try to cache   compiler version information.

[The Cargo documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-reads)

---

> #### Hierarchical structure
>
> Cargo allows local configuration for a particular package as well as
>   global configuration, like git. Cargo extends this to a hierarchical
>   strategy. If, for example, Cargo were invoked in
>   `/projects/foo/bar/baz`, then the following configuration files would
>   be probed for and unified in this order:
>
> - `/projects/foo/bar/baz/.cargo/config`
> - `/projects/foo/bar/.cargo/config`
> - `/projects/foo/.cargo/config`
> - `/projects/.cargo/config`
> - `/.cargo/config`
> - `$HOME/.cargo/config`
>
> With this structure, you can specify configuration per-package, and
>   even possibly check it into version control. You can also specify
>   personal defaults with a configuration file in your home directory.

[The Cargo documentation](http://doc.crates.io/config.html#hierarchical-structure)

Comment: +1 for the mention of configuration files; checking in the configuration in the project is very helpful for contributors!

Answer (score 4):

The default location can be changed by means of the environment variable `$CARGO_HOME`, it overrides the default location which is `$HOME/.cargo`.