# How do I change where `cargo install` places binaries?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am installing racer, rustfmt & rustsym

```
cargo install racer
cargo install rustfmt
cargo install rustsym
```

The packages are being installed in `C:\Users\<UserName>\.cargo`, but I want it to be `C:\Rust\.cargo`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050995/how-can-the-location-of-cargos-configuration-directory-be-overridden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is via `--root`:

```
cargo install --root C:\Rust.cargo racer
```

`CARGO_HOME` and others can be set to override this too. Consult the documentation or [How can the location of cargo's configuration directory be overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050995/how-can-the-location-of-cargos-configuration-directory-be-overridden).

Comment: My Appologies, a little mistake in the question. Fixed it. The solution would be - cargo install --root C:\Rust\.cargo racer